# Can you run jekyll on your own server?

Tags: ruby, git, github, jekyll

Can you run jekyll on your own server or does it have to work with github pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jekyll just produces static html files that you can host on any server. Usually you'll install Jekyll locally and then upload the site files to your server.

Comment: +1 for running a static site generator on a server not making sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's packaged as a RubyGem. Install it via RubyGems:

```
$ gem install jekyll
```

You can run it via the `jekyll` program.

Short answer: yes.